# How do I create a variable in PHP of today's date of MM/DD/YYYY format?

Tags: php

How do I create a variable in PHP of today's date of MM/DD/YYYY format?

I need to input that date as a hidden form field when someone comes onto the site. So I would need to grab today's date and convert it into that format. Thanks.

Answer (score 38):

use the builtin [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

```
$myDate = date('m/d/Y');
```

the string parameter 'm/d/Y' is the returned date pattern. m is for 2 digit months, d for 2 digit day value and Y for 4 digit year value.

Answer (score 11):

```
$Date = date('m/d/Y');
```

Comment: don't forget the ' or " and tack the ; on as well: $date = date('m/d/y');

Answer (score 7):

What about using the function [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) ?
Just have to find the right format ; 'm' for month, 'd' for day, 'Y' for year using four digits, for instance

In your case, something like this, I guess :

```
date("m/d/Y")
```

And if you want another day than now, use the second optional parameter.

Answer (score 6):

May be this one help you :)

```
<?php echo $todaydate = date('m/d/Y'); ?> // 04/27/2016 

<?php echo $todaydate = date('m/d/y'); ?> // 04/27/16 


<?php echo $todaydate = date('Y'); ?> // 2016 

<?php echo $todaydate = date('Y-m-d'); ?> // 2016-04-27
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$currentdate = date('m/d/Y');
echo "The Current Date is: $currentdate";
?>
```

Comment: This question was asked 6 years ago, and 5 minutes later there were 3 answers. Why have you posted one more answer that adds **nothing** to the ones we already have?

Comment: Ok, please don't do this. I am not saying your answer is wrong, just that it is identical to those that have already been given by others, and therefore it isn't useful. It's true that here there were already 3 answers, but they were posted at the same time, immediately after the question was asked. This is accepted. But answering now, adding nothing, really has no sense. It would be different if you were proposing an alternate solution. More info [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291276/are-duplicate-answers-acceptable?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo "Today is " . date("Y/m/d") . "<br>";
echo "Today is " . date("Y.m.d") . "<br>";
echo "Today is " . date("Y-m-d") . "<br>";

?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it. As far as I see, none of these three lines produces an output that corresponds to the question